# php error: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 576192512) (tried to allocate 486801418 bytes) in "file" on line 410

Tags: php, memory, runtime-error

The following program (excerpt) causes this problem:

```
file_put_contents("icecatcategorydata.xml.gz", $xml);
$file = gzopen("icecatcategorydata.xml.gz", "r");
$content = '';
while (($buffer = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $content .= $buffer; // this is line 410 where the error occurs
}
```

I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.4.22 Architecture x86 on Windows 8 64 Bit.
The memory_limit is set to 4000M
No other user uses this system. It is my development computer.

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: I would say... because it's out of memory... You are trying to open that entire file in RAM which is not a good idea. I can hardly imagine that it is a small file.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to handle your data in a better manner.

Comment: lol, SAX parsers anyone?

Comment: why are you reading the file to get the data, when you just wrote the file using the data? Why not just use `$xml` instead of re-creating it in `$content`?

Comment: @dmullings he is using gzopen, so I'm assuming $xml is gzip encoded...

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420oh ok, thanks. I missed that.

Comment: Regardless of the pros and cons of writing and then reading again via a gzopen, unsetting $xml might help.... but there's also the question of where $xml is coming from, it might be possible to work with that directly while remaining within memory constraints

Comment: @Mark Indeed. And even if it's being downloaded, you can stream it directly to disk without keeping it in memory at all, or you may be able to parse it directly while downloading it using `XMLReader`. Either way, the answer is that the OP is using too much memory (d'uh) and needs to avoid using memory by all means.

Comment: Further Explanation: $xml is the gzipped output of a curl_exec call. My plan is to process the xml unzipped output with XPATH expressions using simplexml. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Since that file appears to be ginourmous, you certainly don't want to be opening it by storing it all in memory at once. Even just having it in one variable `$xml` seems suspicious; you should only keep it on disk or write it directly to disk from wherever you get it from, not using `file_put_contents`. After you have written it to disk, open it with `XMLReader`, which will read the file little by little as needed. You can even open a gzipped file directly:

```
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open('compress.zlib:///path/to/file');
```

You'll need to learn how to navigate around in the partially opened XML file using this class, it's a bit trickier than, say, `SimpleXML`. But it's the only realistic option to parse large files. See http://php.net/xmlreader.